# Unexpected ExtJS Error Message: Ext.ComponentManager.register(): Registering duplicate component id "sparklines-tooltip"

Tags: extjs

The following error occurs sometimes during loading of the application. It tends to disapear when I re-open the browser or change something in my app.

Error:

```
[E] Ext.ComponentManager.register(): Registering duplicate component id "sparklines-tooltip"
[...]
Error.js?_dc=1421687747906:103 Uncaught Error: Registering duplicate component id "sparklines-tooltip"
```

Chrome Console Screenshot:
[image: Chrome Console Screenshot]

I did not change the ExtJS sources. I am working with Sencha ExtJS 5, Sencha Cmd and Visual Studio 2013.

When I search in the entire solution It finds this:

```
ext\src\sparkline\Base.js(500):            id: 'sparklines-tooltip',
```

Here is my Application.js

**Application.js**

```
/**
 * The main application class. An instance of this class is created by app.js when it calls
 * Ext.application(). This is the ideal place to handle application launch and initialization
 * details.
 */
Ext.define('ExtTest.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    requires: ['*'],
    name: 'ExtTest',

    models: [
        'vPrd'
    ],

    stores: [
    ],

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'border',
            autoShow: 'true',
            items: [{
                region: 'center',
                xtype: 'app-main'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

The file causing the error is called Api.js and it defines "Ext.ux.google.Api".

**Update:**
According to the posted answer here, I was checking for duplicate IDs of my components. There are none.

**Workaround Found:**
In Application.js I had this line:

```
requires: ['*']
```

It causes Sencha Cmd to include all the packages of ExtJS (also "Ext.ux.google.Api" which I am not using). When I remove it, it works and the app.js is smaller too.
Anyway this is not a real solution. It should be possible to include everything without an error.

Answer (score 2):

the component manager does not allow for duplicate ids like the error reads. You may have components with the id: "sparklines-tooltip" being dynamically generated under certain events this is why the problem is only occurring occasionally. I recommend looking through your code and finding that id, and then adding something to it if it is being dynamically created like a variable counter or something.

Comment: It is actually in the source of ExtJS. I am wondering what google.load.Ext.appyIf.callback means in the console (before second error)

Comment: It will show in the source of ExtJS when the core of it sees two ids it will be notified in extjs core not showing your actual file location where the problem occurs. Here is an example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gmp
the google.load i'm not sure if your Api.js is a file you created or a extjs default file because no more code is given.

Comment: It looks like you have used Ext.define and supplied an id in the config and then re-used the component without overriding the id. check your define's for that particular id. As @Geohut said. its a duplicate id causing your issue

Comment: I did not find any duplicate IDs. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I upvoted your answer, since it was helpful (but it did not provide the solution).  There is no answer to the problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message. I was defining id for some panels. And, I was dynamically creating a viewport, and at the same time, the autoCreateViewport was set to true. This caused the above error. By changing the autoCreateViewport to false, the error went away.

The solution would be, first, perform a text search on the duplicate id. If there is none, then check for panel id that is created dynamically.